# UIImage screenshot loses its quality

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uiimage

I am merging two images and then I take a screenshot by applying this code:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
img_AddText=viewImage;

[dragView removeFromSuperview];
imgV_SelectedImg.image=nil;
imgV_SelectedImg.image=img_AddText;
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(viewImage, nil, nil, nil);
```

The problem is that when the final image loses its quality it blurs.

Answer (score 9):

Try using the withOptions version of UIGraphicsBeginImageContext

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, 0.0);
```

Answer (score 2):

i got the snapshot with good quality and particular location of screen. By this code.

```
-(UIImage *)takeScreenShot
{
    CGRect grabRect;
    grabRect = CGRectMake(0,70,320,260);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(grabRect.size, self.view.opaque, 0.0);
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, -grabRect.origin.x, -grabRect.origin.y);
    [self.view.layer renderInContext:ctx];
    UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return viewImage;
}
```

it gives me excellent snapshot..

Answer (score 1):

I've made a category on `UIImage` class that may help you. It goes like this:

```
+ (UIImage*)imageWithView:(UIView *)view opaque:(BOOL)opaque bgColor:(UIColor*)bgColor{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, opaque, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);

    if(!opaque){
        [bgColor set];
    }
    [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return img;
}
```

It works fine for me. No bluring was detected. Try to use it. If you'll still have it then most likely the problem is in your saving code...

Cheers... :)

Comment: The reason that your image doesn't lose its quality is that you are using `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, opaque, scale)` just like [Dcritelli](http://stackoverflow.com/users/127704/dcritelli)'s [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11020726/608157)

Answer (score 1):

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, 2.0);
this solve my prblem by increasing scale from 1.0 to 2.0

Comment: pass 0 to use the device resolution - future proof yourself and maintain compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Did you provide an image for retina display? You should check it. You might be running in a simulator (in retina).